How do i get rid of this "qlState: '22007', sqlMessage: "Incorrect date value: 'undefined' for column 'issue_date' at row 1"
I am working on a DBMS project - "Hostel Management System". And the issue is that:
On the student page, one of the facilities given to them is to complaint file. Now the data that they enter is to be sent to the backend.
first see the the complaint page:

[![after submitting, check the inspect bar.]
as u can see i get this response:
Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body
: 
(...)
bodyUsed
: 
false
headers
: 
Headers {}
ok
: 
false
redirected
: 
false
status
: 
0
statusText
: 
""
type
: 
"opaque"
url
: 
""

the data is not getting added to the database.
i got this error:
  code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1366,
  sql: '\n' +
    '    INSERT INTO complaint(compType,hos_id,issue,issue_date)\n' +
    '    VALUES\n' +
    '    (\n' +
    "        'undefined',\n" +
    "        'NaN',\n" +
    "        'undefined',\n" +
    "        'undefined'\n" +
    '    );\n' +
    '    ',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  sqlMessage: "Incorrect integer value: 'NaN' for column 'hos_id' at row 1"
}

I tried the following:
1.
This is under the file comp.js -
// Function to handle form submission
async function submitComplaint(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get form data
  var complaintType = document.getElementById('complaintType').value;
  var hostelID = document.getElementById('hostelID').value;
  var issueDescription = document.getElementById('issueDescription').value;
  var issueDate = document.getElementById('issueDate').value;
  console.log(typeof hostelID); // Check the type of hostelID

// Validate hostelID as an integer
if (!Number.isInteger(Number(hostelID))) {
  alert("Hostel ID must be a valid integer.");
  return; // Stop further execution
}
  // Create a data object to send to the backend
  const complaintData = {
    compType: complaintType,
    hos_id: hostelID,
    issue: issueDescription,
    issue_date: issueDate
  };

  console.log(complaintData);


  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts/complaint', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(complaintData)
    });
  
    console.log(response); // Log response from the backend
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }


i made sure that hostel id is integer only. i changed the type of hostelID to number in html:

    <label for="hostelID">Hostel ID:</label>
    <input type="number" id="hostelID" name="hostelID"><br>


I used the parseInt in postControllers.js:

exports.createNewCompaint = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  try {
    let { compType,hos_id,issue,issue_date } = req.body;
    // Convert hos_id to an integer
    hos_id = parseInt(hos_id);
    let postComplaint = new PostComplaint(compType,hos_id,issue,issue_date);
    res.send("Complaint Registered");

    postComplaint = await postComplaint.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Success" });
    console.log(postComplaint);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
};

in the database:
create table try.complaint(
compType VARCHAR(100),
hos_id INT,
issue VARCHAR(500),
issue_date date
);
describe complaint;


i have made sure that the connection is established between backend and mysql. the server was running.
i also tried changing the datatype of hos_id to varchar. but nothing changed. still getting the error. help.

try console.log(parseInt(undefined)) - then you'll see why the hos_id value is NaN ... the most likely cause is that you don't have a body parser in your back end code (are you using express?)

by the way, no point in .json({ message: "Success" }); since you are getting an opaque response

tried changing the datatype of hos_id to varchar. but nothing changed. still getting the error you wouldn't get the SAME error at all - since hos_id isn't expected to be a number any more - check again to see what the ACTUAL error is, rather than assuming it's the same

What's the exact output of console.log(complaintData);?

This is not a database issue as @JaromandaX also indicated. The sql quey log indicates that you are passing NaN and undefined as parameters to the sql query indicating that your server-side js code could not parse  your post input parameters correctly.

We need to see the backend endpoint for: /posts/complaint, as mentioned be the others this is most likely where the issue is
